# showbreak causing cursor to show in wrong place

Tags: vim

I use `set showbreak=↪`. When my text breaks the cursor is off by a space. So the text actually appears a space before the cursor. I don't recall this happening in the past, and this has been in my vimrc for quite some time. What causes this?

```
" same result
set showbreak=↳
cpoptions+=n

" non-extended characters resolve the issue
set showbreak=...\ 
set showbreak=~
```

This occurs in vim and gvim. I should also mention, this is preceded by:

```
scriptencoding utf-8
set encoding=utf-8
```

Comment: Did you update vim recently? (What version of vim are you running?)

Comment: It turns out I had updated recently. I don't know what caused the breakage, but patch 7.4.478 resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is fixed by [patch 7.4.478](https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/detail?r=fcb898dea2bc8b6e89172cb48ef26c56cb79cfdd)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much. This did correct the issue.

Arch users, this is updated in gvim-hg from the AUR as noted by @angelic_sedition.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that this happened to me the other day when I updated gvim. As Christian Brabandt pointed out, it's been fixed. I'm using Arch, so I just updated to `gvim-hg` from the AUR. Alternatively I guess that you could downgrade.

Comment: Oh great. I've just grabbed that from the AUR, and it did correct the issue. I have to mark the other though due to many individuals not using Arch... yet, so the specific patch is more widely correct. Thank you.